# Displaying OpenCV iplimage data structures with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, opencv, format-conversion

Here is my current code (language is Python):

```
newFrameImage = cv.QueryFrame(webcam)
newFrameImageFile = cv.SaveImage("temp.jpg",newFrameImage)
wxImage = wx.Image("temp.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wxImage, (0,0), (wxImage.GetWidth(), wxImage.GetHeight()))
```

I'm trying to display an iplimage captured from my webcam in a wxPython window. The problem is I don't want to store the image on hard disk first. Is there any way to convert an iplimage into another image format in memory? Any other solution?

I found a few "solutions" to this problem in other languages, but I'm still having trouble with this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with StringIO

```
stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
wxImage = wx.ImageFromStream(stream)
```

you can check more detail in \wx\lib\embeddedimage.py

just my 2 cents.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? Where does data come from?

Comment: I have found that opencv does not have api to write ImageData into stream http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#highgui_func_index
so finding some other ways.

Comment: Thank you for even trying, I appreciate it

Comment: Seems there is direct converter from ipl images to wxImage 

http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid4A270123EB2BF8B15C8F6F620770EA6D2821F509.aspx?s=opencv

but seems like we need to port to python ourselves because its c++, 

* IPL image structure is seems based on RGB format too. 

http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00041000000000000000

Answer (score 6):

What you have to do is:

```
frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.cam) # Get the frame from the camera
cv.CvtColor(frame, frame, cv.CV_BGR2RGB) # Color correction
                         # if you don't do this your image will be greenish
wxImage = wx.EmptyImage(frame.width, frame.height) # If your camera doesn't give 
                         # you the stream size, you might have to use (640, 480)
wxImage.SetData(frame.tostring()) # convert from cv.iplimage to wxImage
wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, wxImage, (0,0), 
                (wxImage.GetWidth(), wxImage.GetHeight()))
```

I figured oyt  out how to do this by looking at the [Python OpenCV cookbook](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html#opencv-to-pil-image) and at the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithImages#PIL_.28Python_Imaging_Library.29).

Comment: I'm well aware that this post is a year old, but it's the current highest ranking SO question on Google for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this question is old but I came here like everybody else searching for the answer. Several versions of wx, numpy, and opencv after the above solutions I figured I'd share a fast solution using cv2 and numpy images.

**This is how to convert a NumPy array style image as used in OpenCV2 into a bitmap you can then set to a display element in wxPython (as of today**):

```
import wx, cv2
import numpy as np

# Start with a numpy array style image I'll call "source"

# convert the colorspace to RGB from cv2 standard BGR, ensure input is uint8
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.uint8(source), cv2.cv.CV_BGR2RGB) 

# get the height and width of the source image for buffer construction
h, w = img.shape[:2]

# make a wx style bitmap using the buffer converter
wxbmp = wx.BitmapFromBuffer(w, h, img)

# Example of how to use this to set a static bitmap element called "bitmap_1"
self.bitmap_1.SetBitmap(wxbmp)
```

Tested 10 minutes ago :)

This uses the built in wx function [BitmapFromBuffer](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/wxFunctions.html#BitmapFromBuffer) and takes advantage of the NumPy buffer interface so that all we have to do is swap the colors to get those in the expected order.